# How do I grep a file in a smb mount point without using mount or fstab?

Tags: linux, command-line, grep, samba, smb

I don't have permission to mount a smb share with the mount command or by using /etc/fstab, but I'm able to use the smb protocol in Nautilus (smb://10.1.1.1/share), for example ...
s
Is it possible to grep a file or use any command in it in these conditions like I do in local files?

I'm running openSUSE 13.1 with LXDE.

```
$ uname -a
Linux thom 3.11.6-4-desktop #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Oct 30 18:04:56 UTC 2013 (e6d4a27) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ mount
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=944020k,nr_inodes=236005,mode=755)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
tmpfs on /var/run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,mode=755)
/dev/sda2 on /home type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)

$ ls -a ~/.gvfs
ls: não é possível acessar /home/thom/.gvfs: Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado
```

Comment: Which distribution are you using? Please post the output of `ls -a ~/.gvfs` and `mount` when the share is mounted.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add more info, don't put it in the comments. What is the output of `mount`? You have still not answered which linux you are using, also tell us which desktop environment. Gnome? KDE? Unity? Cinnamon?

Comment: Why don't you just use smbclient(1) from SAMBA to fetch the file and do grep locally?

Comment: done terdon. because it's not as fast as I need Sami Laine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nautilus uses [GVFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GVFS) internally. GVFS itself only caters for applications that use the Glib library to access files.

Make sure that you have the [gvfs-fuse](https://www.suse.com/LinuxPackages/packageRouter.jsp?product=server&version=11&service_pack=sp1&architecture=i386&package_name=gvfs-fuse) package installed. This package contains the program `gvfs-fuse-daemon` which makes all GVFS filesystems available as normal mounted filesystems.

`gvfs-fuse-daemon` should start automatically when you first access a GVFS system, for example when you connect to a remote Samba drive in Nautilus. If it doesn't, try doing

```
mkdir -p ~/.gvfs
/usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-fuse-daemon ~/.gvfs
```

GVFS filesystems are all mounted in subdirectories of `~/.gvfs`. Some recent distributions use `/run/user/500/gvfs` instead, where `500` is your user id (you can display it with `id -u`).

You can even do the mounting on the command line:

```
gvfs-mount smb://10.1.1.1/share
```

Comment: Do you have to make the `~/.gvfs` dir? I thought it would get auto-crated when you started up the daemon?

Comment: @slm I'm not sure, but surely it can't hurt to create it.

Comment: Agreed - I was just wondering if you knew if it did/didn't.

Comment: Thanks, I can see my mount point in /run/user/1000/gvfs. Problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

When you access the SMB shares via `smb://`, in Nautilus, the GNOME desktop is facilitating the mounting of the share behind the scenes. You'll typically see these when you run the `mount` command.

#### Example

```
$ mount 
...
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
```

If you `cd` to this directory, `/run/user/1000/gvfs` you'll be able to access the filesystem from a shell and use `grep` or whatever tools you want.

#### OpenSUSE specifically

I came across this thread, titled: [Thread: gvfs: Permission denied](http://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/482010-gvfs-Permission-denied), which shows that the gvfs daemon does in fact mount things under `/run/user/$UID/gvfs` on the newer versions of OpenSUSE like other distros, so the above should be the correct place to look for any Samba mounted shares.

*excerpt*

```
mbj@mortenb-ws2:~> grep gvfs /proc/mounts
gvfs-fuse-daemon /run/user/mbj/gvfs fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=100 0 0
```

Comment: Is it `/run/user/$UID/gvfs` on SuSE, and not `~/.gvfs` like on Debian/Ubuntu? [These](https://forums.suse.com/archive/index.php/t-988.html) [forum](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/454671-kde-and-samba-shares-How-to-mount-them) threads mention `~/.gvfs`.

Comment: @Gilles - I'm not entirely sure, this was an example to show that the path will show up when you run the mount command not necessarily that the OP's path would be `/run/..` vs. `~/.gvfs`.

Comment: I looked into it and distributions are moving as they adapt to `/run`, so it's probably a matter of version.

Comment: @Gilles - yeah I took a bit of a gamble in saying that dir. since he's on a newer ver. of OpenSUSE.

Comment: @Gilles - found a thread that shows they're using /run/user/...`. At least on the newer vers. of SuSE.